# How to hide the tab bar in specific screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my react-native application I have a tab bar. Each tab is a different stack.
In one of the stacks there is a screen for which I want to hide the tab navigator.
I tried to do something like that on the said screen:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    console.log(`routeName = ${routeName}`);
    if (routeName === "ScreenName"){
        navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: false});
    }else {
        navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: true});
    }
}, [navigation, route]);
```

However I get an error that says:

```
Argument of type '{ tabBarVisible: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<StackNavigationOptions>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'tabBarVisible' does not exist in type 'Partial<StackNavigationOptions>'.
```

How can I hide the tab bar on the specific screen correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**On React Navigation v5/v6**

Suppose there are two tabs. Each tab contains stack screens.
Let's call "tab1" for first tab and "tab2Stack" for second tab.

On the second tab first need get the parent using the following snippet

```
const parent = navigation.getParent();
```

Then we can set ***`tabBarStyle`*** on ***`parent.setOptions()`*** using the following snippet

```
parent.setOptions({
        tabBarStyle: {
              position: "absolute",
              bottom: -(SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.112), // adjust the size according to your tab bar height
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.112,
              paddingTop: 20,
            },
      });
```

Here is a full working expo [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pieamo/hide-tab-bar).

If the expo snack is not running then just download and run it on your machine.